# Firebase security rules for admin read only even though they're set to false

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a node inside my app that users can write to but they can't read to.

```
let specialNodeRef = dbRef.child("specialNode").childByAutoId()
specialNodeRef.updateChildValues(dict)
```

Is there a way I can set the rules so that only admin can read from that node even though the rules are set to false outside of using the console?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "specialNode": {
        ".read": false, // users can't read but admin can
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users running the Firebase Admin SDK, or accessing the database through the Firebase console, access the database with administrative privileges. They can always read/write, so are not affected by the `".read": false`.

If you want to declare one/some of the users of your application as having specific privileges, you can include their Firebase Authentication UID in the rules:

```
".read": "auth.uid = 'uidOfLance'"
```

A bit more flexible is to store the UID of each such user in the database in a form like:

```
"admins": {
  "uidOfLance": true,
  "uidOfPuf": true
}
```

You can then check for the UID in your security rules:

```
".read": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
```

Comment: If I'm running the app on my device and I want to bypass the rules how do I go about doing that? That's the part I'm lost at. Basically on m device I can also write to that node but I can read from too. I want to avoid the console for that part.

Comment: I think we might be talking about a different "administrator" here. What defines an administrator for your app? Is it just you yourself, as in a Firebase Authentication user with a specific UID?

Comment: Yes exactly, I apologize for not being clear. I'm the only person who has access to the db. Ahhhh I see where your going with this. I can do something like: "specialNode": {
        ".read": "false || auth.uid === 'mySpecificUID'",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }

Comment: Yup, that's the simplest way. Alternatively make a list of such UIDs (e.g. store `"uidOfLance": true` under `/admins`) and then check in rules: `".read": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the much assisted help! :)

Comment: I like the idea you posted because it works well if someone has a team of people they want to have admin bypass privileges. Very good idea. I’m surprised I haven’t seen any other answers like this.

Comment: hi, I have a new requirement where admin (myself and a few others) wants to read from the users node, would it go like this: **"users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }**

Comment: That looks OK at first glance. If it doesn't work, please open a  new question with a new [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok thanks. Either way I let you know the results by tomorrow morning. Thanks