# How to allow one admin user to write Firebase Database? Without changing all the other rules below

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to keep my specific rules regarding the users and players,  but I want a suprior rule that we allow an admin user to write without limitation, it should be as "OR" , meaning either you're an admin or the rules below.  (Without starting to edit every table below)

```
  "rules": {   
      "scores": {
          "$sid": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": "root.child('game').child($sid).child(auth.uid).exists()&& 
                auth!=null"
              }
            },...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a rule at a higher level for admin users, for example if you recognize an admin by their UID, you can do:

```
{
  "rules": { 
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'theuidofheadmin'",
    "scores": {
      "$sid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "root.child('game').child($sid).child(auth.uid).exists()&& 
                  auth!=null"
      }
    },...
```

So now the admin has write permissions on anything under the root, and you can't take those away anymore, but anyone else still needs to meet the requirements for each specific node.

Also see:

- [How to only allow one admin user to write Firebase Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771808/how-to-only-allow-one-admin-user-to-write-firebase-database)
- [Firebase security rules for admin read only even though they're set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594983/firebase-security-rules-for-admin-read-only-even-though-theyre-set-to-false)
- [How to set up Firebase Realtime Database to allow developer to mark admins in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046208/how-to-set-up-firebase-realtime-database-to-allow-developer-to-mark-admins-in-th)
- [firebase realtime db security rule to allow specific users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853428/firebase-realtime-db-security-rule-to-allow-specific-users)
- [Firebase Realtime Database rules to allow a single user Write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391764/firebase-realtime-database-rules-to-allow-a-single-user-write-access)